# full screen google react-native codebar scanner

Tags: android, react-native, camera

I'm trying to make the following example become fullscreen:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, StyleSheet, Text, View, Alert } from 'react-native';
import BarcodeScanner from 'react-native-barcode-scanner-google';


export default class BarcodeApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{
        flex: 1
      }}>
          <BarcodeScanner
              style={{
                flex: 1
              }}
              onBarcodeRead={({data, type}) => {
                  // handle your scanned barcodes here!
                  // as an example, we show an alert:
                  Alert.alert(`Barcode '${data}' of type '${type}' was scanned.`);
              }}
          />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('brcodegooglern', () => BarcodeApp);
```

The problem is: At the moment, on my physical device, the screen renders only at half of its size.

I also wish to place elements like text and image on top of the camera visualization screen.

How to accomplish that?

PS: I'm using react-native-barcode-scanner-google instead of react-native-camera because the performance of onBarcodeRead seems to be slightly better.